# Assert for nullable parameters

Tags: javascript, chai, assertions

Is there any clean way for asserting a *nullable* parameter with `chai.js`? As an example, let's say I have the following method:

```
public set numberOrNull ( value : number ) {

    chai.expect( value ).to.be.a( "number" );
    this._number = value;
}
```

If I pass `null` to this method, I'd still get an exception from chai. I can of course go for something like this, but was wondering if there is any better way for doing this:

```
if ( null !== value ) {
    chai.expect( value ).to.be.a( "number" );
}

this._number = value;
```

Comment: I assume you are using typescript, as your params are typed. Thus, there should not be a need to check for null, as typescript should catch that on compile time. Regarding tests; if the value can be null OR a number, you should write 2 independent tests to reflect both outcomes

Comment: @japrescott I'm writing typescript, however these are 'not' my unit-tests. this is part of my run-time assertions/preconditions, so typescript compiler won't help. also all types in typescript are nullable, meaning that whether I pass a value or null it will all work with no problem.

Comment: Typescript2.0 added [non-nullable types.](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/09/27/typescript-2-0-non-nullable-types). As this is production and not unit-test code, I strongly advice NOT to use chai/assertion in the wild You should rely on typescript and your unit-tests and trust that your code is battleproof in the wild. You should check the type in the wild (if its user-input), but don't throw an error, just return

Comment: @japrescott I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the heads-up. As for run-time assertions/preconditions, I don't particularly see any problem with that, but I will try to read up about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `satisfy`:

```
expect(value).to.satisfy(value => value === null || typeof value === 'number');
```

Don't want sound offensive, but I think it would be cleaner when the respective function you want to test does not allow `null` as a parameter value. From my point of view this would result in a function which is easier to reason about.

**Edit:** Overlooked that you use TypeScript. If so, I'm also with the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994957/assert-for-nullable-parameters/39995129?noredirect=1#comment67268525_39994957) by @japrescott and rely on the capabilities of the language.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of satisfy method, but I rather keep it consistent and use the chai asserts (for number I mean), instead of writing custom assertion.

Comment: Ah okay, yes, makes sense. Okay, I'm not aware of a defined assertion which allows those kind of check. Sorry :/

Comment: But if function doesn't accept null, then how would you set the value of that property to null (that's the expected behaviour). would you make a setSomethingToNull method?